# HtmlUnit use HtmlSearchInput to search

Tags: java, web-crawler, htmlunit, html-input

I am trying to search using an input which is of type search. But doesn't seem to work.
It works in the website when I type a search string in the search input and press enter. But can't get it done using my code. How can I resolve this?

```
HtmlSearchInput searchBox = (HtmlSearchInput) page.getByXPath("//input[@class='searchinput1']").get(1);
searchBox.setValueAttribute("Toys");
HtmlPage page2 = (HtmlPage) searchBox.type('\n');

Thread.sleep(2000);
WEB_CLIENT.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
WEB_CLIENT.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(350000);

HtmlPage page3= (HtmlPage) WEB_CLIENT.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage();

System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(page.asText()).html());
System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(page2.asText()).html());
System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(page3.asText()).html());
```

Comment: try to use type() instead of setValueAttribute

Comment: It makes no sense to parse the asText output - this is only plain text, use as Html instead. System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(page.asText()).html());

Comment: @RBRi thanks, after using type, it loads the page partially and says there's been an error loading the page. What am I missing? Is web scraping blocked for this website?

Comment: WEB_CLIENT.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

Comment: @RBRi thank you. I just noticed that the website crashes many times while using manually  as well

Comment: btw - from my point of view there is no reason to use Jsoup and HtmlUnit together - HtmlUnit can do everything for you ;-) if not please open an issue on GitHub